# Where did Windows 8 go, can I still access it?

Tags: dual-boot, windows, uefi

I just downloaded the latest version of Ubuntu 13 and am excited to be in the world of Linux and learn more about how this open operating system works. My question is now, where did Window's 8 go.

I downloaded Ubuntu to a writeable DVD then followed the instructions to to change the UEFI settings so that my PC would allow me to install Ubuntu (it was a lot easier then expected).

My questions are:

1. Where is Windows 8 now?
2. Is it gone for good?
3. Can I still access it?
4. How?

Thanks!

Comment: You could try holding down the shift key on boot. Grub _should_ always display the boot menu if there is another operating system found, but just in case this is worth a try.

Comment: Tried that, wasn't able to boot windows. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Hmmm.. first thing I would try is to boot into Ubuntu (either the install on your HDD, or boot from the DVD), and either run gparted (graphical partition manager), or fdisk (from a terminal: sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda) and make sure the NTFS partitions are still there. If they are, I think I would try booting from your Windows install DVD (if you have one), or some sort of Windows recovery disk, in order to restore the Windows boot loader..

Comment: If you haven't got a recovery disk, it looks like you might be able to download a Win8/8.1 iso from MS: http://bit.ly/1jYnjTU Not sure if this would work with an OEM key though. There are various tools that can recover your key, but you may need to mount your HDD on another Windows machine to use them.

Answer (score 0):

To enter console or terminal at left top go to Applications -> Accessories -> Terminal

Click on terminal and in the screen that appears type sudo update grub.

This will update your grub conf and i hope this can solve your problem.

Let me know if it works.

Comment: If it is there, how do I use Windows? When I restart it takes me right into Ubuntu, it doesn't let me choose like a dual boot. How do I load windows 8?

Comment: Open your ubuntu desktop enter console and type sudo update grub
and restart your ubuntu.

let me know if it works :)

Comment: Being so new to Ubuntu and any Linux OS I'm not sure what you mean by this. What is console and where do I type 'sudo update grub'? Will it just boot windows?